# Why does this c++ code not compile in g++ 4.8.2

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm trying to compile C++ pulse chess engine [0] using g++ 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 14.04 environment).

I get the following errors at linking stage:

```
Linking CXX executable pulse-
CMakeFiles/pulse.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `pulse::MoveGenerator::MoveGenerator()':
/home/user/cpp/movegenerator.h:15: undefined reference to `pulse::MoveList<pulse::MoveEntry>::MoveList()'
libcore.so: undefined reference to `pulse::MoveList<pulse::MoveEntry>::rateFromMVVLVA()'
libcore.so: undefined reference to `pulse::MoveList<pulse::RootEntry>::sort()'
libcore.so: undefined reference to `pulse::MoveList<pulse::RootEntry>::MoveList()'
libcore.so: undefined reference to `pulse::MoveList<pulse::MoveEntry>::sort()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I run the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c movelist.cpp && nm movelist.o | grep sort
```

I get the output

```
0000000000000000 W _ZN5pulse8MoveListINS_9MoveEntryEE4sortEv
0000000000000000 W _ZN5pulse8MoveListINS_9RootEntryEE4sortEv
```

when using 4.9.1, but no output when using 4.8.2.

**Why is that g++ 4.9.1 generates the sort function while 4.8.2 does not, is it a bug in the compiler or in the pulse source code?**

**EDIT:**

As stated in the pointed out duplicate question "Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?", I don't get it then, how does it work in g++ 4.9.1?
The movelist header:

```
#include "value.h"
#include "move.h"

#include <array>
#include <memory>

namespace pulse {

/**
 * This class stores our moves for a specific position. For the root node we
 * will populate pv for every root move.
 */
template<class T> 
class MoveList {
private:
  static const int MAX_MOVES = 256;

public:
  std::array<std::shared_ptr<T>, MAX_MOVES> entries;
  int size = 0; 

  MoveList();

  void sort();
  void rateFromMVVLVA();
};

class MoveVariation {
public:
  std::array<int, Depth::MAX_PLY> moves;
  int size = 0; 
};

class MoveEntry {
public:
  int move = Move::NOMOVE;
  int value = Value::NOVALUE;
};

class RootEntry : public MoveEntry {
public:
  MoveVariation pv;
};

}
```

The movelist source:

```
#include "movelist.h"

#include <cassert>

namespace pulse {

template class MoveList<MoveEntry>;
template class MoveList<RootEntry>;

template<class T>
MoveList<T>::MoveList() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i) {
    entries[i] = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T());
  }  
}

/**
 * Sorts the move list using a stable insertion sort.
 */
template<class T> 
void MoveList<T>::sort() {
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    std::shared_ptr<T> entry(entries[i]);

    int j = i; 
    while ((j > 0) && (entries[j - 1]->value < entry->value)) {
      entries[j] = entries[j - 1];
      --j;
    }  

    entries[j] = entry;
  }  
}

/**
 * Rates the moves in the list according to "Most Valuable Victim - Least Valuable Aggressor".
 */
template<class T> 
void MoveList<T>::rateFromMVVLVA() {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    int move = entries[i]->move;
    int value = 0; 

    int piecetypeValue = PieceType::getValue(Piece::getType(Move::getOriginPiece(move)));
    value += PieceType::KING_VALUE / piecetypeValue;

    int target = Move::getTargetPiece(move);
    if (Piece::isValid(target)) {
      value += 10 * PieceType::getValue(Piece::getType(target));
    }

    assert(value >= (PieceType::KING_VALUE / PieceType::KING_VALUE)
      && value <= (PieceType::KING_VALUE / PieceType::PAWN_VALUE) + 10 * PieceType::QUEEN_VALUE);

    entries[i]->value = value;
  }
}
```

[0] https://github.com/fluxroot/pulse/tree/master/src/main/cpp

Comment: @0x499602D2 Stop wielding that dupe-hammer so keenly, man!

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without seeing where the sort() method method gets invoked, and how. I do not see where sort() gets invoked, in the code samples you included in this question.

Comment: Move the two lines that start with `template class` to the end of the source file. The duplicate q doesn't apply, you actually can define templates in source files (sometimes).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I included the link to the github repository, sort gets invoked in the movegenerator.cpp at line 64.

Comment: @n.m., it worked, though i do not really understand why and this all thing with templates defined in header or source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

Move the two lines that start with template class to the end of the source file.

### The explanation

This source uses explicit template instantiation (14.7.2). It is perfectly OK to define the template in the source file (not in the header) as long as only the explicit instantiations of the template are used in the entire program. In this case, these would be `MoveList<MoveEntry>` and `MoveList<RootEntry>`.

However, there is a problem: the explicit specialization must appear *after* the template *definition* (14.7.2/4)

> A declaration of a function template, a variable template, a member function or static data member of a class template, or a member function template of a class or class template shall precede an explicit instantiation of that entity. A definition of a class template, a member class of a class template, or a member class template of a class or class template shall precede an explicit instantiation of that entity unless the explicit instantiation is preceded by an explicit specialization of the entity with the same template arguments.

Why g++ 4.9 does not enforce this is anyone's guess.